# RefTeX how to search for multiple articles to be included in a single cite macro

Tags: reftex

The RefTeX manual clearly describes how to mark multiple entries in a search buffer an insert them into a single `\cite` command, but how can you get the search buffer to contain results from multiple search terms?

For example, if I want to cite two books with different authors I need to use two different search terms to find the entries in my BibTEX database but I want them to appear in the same cite command I need them to be in the same search buffer.  I have tried regular expressions like `author1|author2` and `author1,author2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching for `Author1\|Author2` works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of the escape character.  Is this syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, indirectly. The help for `reftex-citations` mentions that it accepts a regular expression. Emacs' flavour of regular expressions is documented in the manual; section 15.6 "Backslash in Regular Expressions" mentions the syntax for alternatives.