# Including mutiple citations in single \cite command using RefTeX, AUCTeX

Tags: bibliographies, citing, auctex, reftex

I am trying to generate citations that include multiple references to different works, e.g. `\cite{A,B}` giving `[A,B]` in the text. I cannot seem to figure out how to use RefTeX+AUCTeX (in Emacs 27.1) to include multiple citations.

There is a similar question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425883/emacs-auctex-reftex-and-biblatexs-multicite-commands) that shows how to manipulate RefTeX, but in my workflow I still cannot seem to use `\cites` to query for multiple regexes and include those in the same `\cite{}` command.
I have also tried hitting `?`, and this suggests `n/p` to go to the next/previous entry, but this does not actually do anything on my end. Can it be that there exists some clash on my system that prevents the next/previous entry commands to work?
Note that manually including the multiple entries, e.g. `\cite{A,B}` does generate correct behavior -- so my LaTeX/bibliography distro supports multiple citations in a single `\cite` command.

How do you search the database multiple times and include several different bibliography entries into a single `\cite` command?

### MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\bibliography{plain}

\begin{document}

Some citation~\cite{lamport94}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{texbook}
Donald E. Knuth (1986) \emph{The \TeX{} Book}, Addison-Wesley Professional.

\bibitem{lamport94}
Leslie Lamport (1994) \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system}, Addison
Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd ed.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Commands used: `C-c [`

Comment: When you call `reftex-citation` (`C-c [`), you'll first go through a dispatcher to choose the citation command, after that, you're queried for a regex with which the entries are searched for. After that, you get a list of possible entries matching your regex. You can select multiple entries with `m` (navigating with `n`/`p`, or whatever else). Once you're done, exit with `a` (for "all", I guess), and marked entries will be inserted in a comma separated list for your citation command.

Comment: Yes, but this does not allow me to select multiple entries. I want to select distinct entries, e.g. `texbook` and `lamport94` as in the example. I cannot seem to select multiple distinct entries that do not appear in the same regex.

Comment: See also the problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68285/reftex-how-to-search-for-multiple-articles-to-be-included-in-a-single-cite-macro), but this does not work for me as it always selects the final query.

Comment: I have now pinpointed the main problem: [`vertico`](https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/doc/vertico.html) (I got the hint for the completion framework messing with it from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58182/38948)). Turns out it was the completion framework that is messing with `RefTeX`. I will try to come up with a solution and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue turned out to be my Emacs completion framework [`vertico`](https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/doc/vertico.html).
This completed my Regex queries and when using `TAB` or `RET` it only included the currently selected in the Vertico prompt.
I can still execute the Regex (e.g. not the input suggested by Vertico) by using `vertico-exit-input` (with default binding `M-RET`). In this way the original Regex (e.g. `Author1\|Author2`) can be executed, multiple entries can be marked, using `m`, in the `RefTeX` selection buffer and inserted in a single `\cite` command using `a`.

Comment: This is actually part of the learning curve for new users of both Vertico and Ivy. The default binding for `RET` leaves completion selecting the current candidate. If you want to leave with the current input, whether it partially matches a candidate or not, you need a different binding: `M-RET` for Vertico, and `C-M-j` for Ivy.